# xinit not displaying to the PiTFT touch screen when call from the rc.local script

Tags: pitft, bash

Adafruit PiTFT screen working perfetly with my Raspberry Pi. I can run my application using the command xinit /home/pi/Desktop/MyApp from the command line. The application will display in the PiTFT touch screen.

To start this application automatically I placed this command "xinit /home/pi/Desktop/MyApp" in rc.loacal script but the application is launching to HDMI monitor instead of PiTFT touch screen.

I tried "`framebuffer=/dev/fb1 xinit /home/pi/Desktop/MyApp`" too

I noticed when I run xinit in terminal by using sudo the display goes to HDMI monitor "`sudo xinit /home/pi/Desktop/MyApp`"